# HiberNate Filter with annotaions in one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a class Person which can have 4 type of addresses and there could be multiple  number of adresses corresponding to a single type of address.

```
public class Person{
 Set<Address> addresses;
}

public class Address{
private int phoneNumber;   
private Type addressType;
}

public Enum Type{
Buisness,
Personal,
X,
Y   
}
```

So what i want to implement is when a person object is populated List of Addesses of a particular type should be populated with a particular type of address.
however i wish to specify which type of address to be populated at run time. 
i think its possible through hibernate Filter XML config's but i want to implement it with annotations only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@Filter annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters) to filter out data at runtime.

```
public class Person{

     @Filter(name="filterAddressType", condition=":addressType = addressType")
     Set<Address> addresses;
}
```

And at runtime you can apply filter data via session as below:

```
session.enableFilter("filterAddressType").setParameter("addressType ", "Home");
```